# Can't read key from registry

Tags: delphi, registry

I heared that Windows creates a unique key for a PC which is called "MachineID". I found two locations in my registry. Only the location "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography" should be correct. I try to read the value by this function:

```
    Function GetMaschineID:string;
var
Reg : TRegistry;

//HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MSNMessenger    =   {dd239a44-fa0d-43ff-a51c-5561d3e39de3}
//HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography   =   a06b0ee0-b639-4f55-9972-146776bcd5e4
begin
Reg := TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ);
try
Reg.Rootkey:=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE; //Hauptschlüssel
//Reg.RootKey:=HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
if Reg.OpenKey('SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\',false) then //Unterschlüssel öffnen
//if Reg.OpenKey('Software\Microsoft\MSNMessenger\',false) then //Unterschlüssel öffnen
    begin
    Result:=Reg.ReadString('MachineGuid');
    end;
finally
     Reg.Free;
end;
end;
```

This version results in an empty string; you see as comment the result from the registry. The second version for "hkey_Current_user" brings the expected string result.

What is wrong with my code or are parts of the registry read protected?

Comment: What is wrong with reading from current user?

Comment: It seems to be there for different usage, maybe an old application (Messenger???), has a different value (see code above) and the source is definitively not the windows installer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Possible explanation 1**

For `HKLM` you are subject to [registry redirection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232.aspx). You have a 32 bit process and are trying to read a key from the 64 bit view of the registry. By default, your 32 bit process is redirected to the 32 bit view, which (implementation detail) lives under `Wow6432Node`.

Use the [`KEY_WOW64_64KEY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384129.aspx) access flag to read from the 64 bit view. As detailed here: [How can I read 64-bit registry key from a 32-bit process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121044/)

**Possible explanation 2**

Your call to `OpenKey` fails for keys under `HKLM` because you are requesting write access and standard user does not have write access to `HKLM`. Use `OpenKeyReadOnly` instead.

**Other advice**

At the very least you should have debugged this a bit more. Does the call to `Reg.OpenKey` succeed or fail? You should have debugged enough to know that. Perhaps you did but did not say. If `Reg.OpenKey` failed then explanation 2 is most likely. Even then, you may subsequently suffer from the other problem.

Note also that your function does not assign to the function result variable, or raise an error, if the call to `Reg.OpenKey` fails. I would expect that the compiler would have warned you about that.

Comment: I'm sorry I wrote "results in an empty string"  this means that Openkey works and the empty string is a result of the "readstring" line. I think your explanation 1 sounds correct. I must understand, needs a moment

Comment: An empty string is likely what you'd see if `OpenKey` failed because you did not assign to Result in that case, and managed types are default initialized.

Comment: Anyway, your code example you gave with your answer works very well, Thank you

Comment: Are you running elevated? Do you really need to? Because OpenKey should fail for HKLM.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "elevated". Following code works [Codelink](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1G8zlQsH9jVY1DDf3cu_s4xNwfCF73vHKTO84Nq9eV5Y/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Only if you disabled UAC, are running virtualized, or UAC is enabled and you are elevated, running as admin.

Answer (score -1):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    registry: TRegistry;
begin
    Registry := TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ OR KEY_WOW64_64KEY);
    try
        registry.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
        if (registry.KeyExists('\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL')) and
       (registry.OpenKeyReadOnly('\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL')) then
        begin
            showmessage(registry.ReadString('SQLEXPRESS'));
            registry.CloseKey;
        end
        else showmessage('failed');
    finally
        registry.Free;
    end;
end;
```